# Create separate classes for insert and save

Tags: language-agnostic

Is this a good idea? Instead of create a class with two method (`insert` and `update`) and two validation methods (`validateInsert` and `validateUpdate`), create three classes: one called `ProductDB`, another `ProductInsert` (with methods Insert and Validate) and another `ProductUpdate` (with same methods of ProductInsert).

Is this more readable, flexible and testable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PaulG's answer leans more towards the traditional domain object pattern, which I'm not in favor of. Personally, my preference is to have a separate class for each process (like your ProductInsert and ProductUpdate). This is akin to what one sees in the simple bank example where Deposit is a instance of a class as opposed to a method on a BankAccount class. When you start thinking about business processes that have more stuff, like rules and actions to be taken and auditing/persistence of the action itself (say a ProductInsert table to track insertions), the more you realize the business process should be a first class citizen in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a language-independent question. I would just create the one class and call it Product, and have the appropriate methods within the class. Think about what a mess it would be when actually instantiating your separate objects (unless you have static methods).

Also having a concrete Product class will allow you to store object specific information.

Ex:

`Product myProduct = new Product()`

`myProduct.name = "cinnamon toast crunch"`

`myProduct.price = 3.99`

In my opinion have separate classes would make your code a lot less readable and testable.